# Custom List View Item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-custom-view

I try to create custom list view with four column. 
Like This

[image]

Here My Code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewchalan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="5555"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewdate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="5555"
     android:paddingLeft="20dip"

    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewstatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="555"
     android:paddingLeft="20dip"
   />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/viewdetail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Out Put file..**

[image]
But In my custom list view item when challan number is different then all data moved .

Plz help me I am new in android and i don't know how i can fix this problem.

Thanks In Advance

Any Help is Appreciated.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your output?

Comment: 1) your `LinearLayout` doesn't have `orientation` set. 2) The `RelativeLayout` is absolutely pointless.

Comment: How you are able to set android:orientation="horizontal" in relative layout?? Hmm Amazing

Comment: Thanks for replay I am post screen shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewchalan"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5555" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewdate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5555" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewstatus"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="555" />

     <Button
    android:id="@+id/viewdetail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much   U save my lot of time

Answer (score 1):

Try setting width to zero and use layout_weight to make each entry the same width so they line up as nice columns.  Also, set the container LinearLayout width to match_parent.  For instance:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/viewchalan"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="5555"
      android:paddingLeft="10dip"
      />

   ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Set layout_width and layout_weight like that for all your items.

Comment: i set but text view all text having not same digit then out is not showing perfect

Answer (score 0):

Put your values in a TableLayout. This is exactly what TableLayout is for.

Comment: Thanks in replay but in tableview how i can set column

Comment: under TableLayout add a  TableRow. In TableRow, each child View becomes a column. i usually add a vertical oriented LinearLayout for each of my columns, and then put the column layout in each of those. 

Here is a good tutorial: http://androidexample.com/Table_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=74&aaid=98